# How to store a string in a empty list and display the results in a listbox

Tags: python, list, tkinter, listbox, python-3.6

Hello Python community,

Im using Python 3.6 and Im stumped on how to display a stored item in an empty list to a list box. Can anyone evaluate my code and tell me what I'm missing? Thanks in advance!

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Name Entry")
root.geometry("240x250")

mylist = []

def get_data(l):
    l.append(box1.get())
    print(l)

label1 = Label(root,text = "ID:",height = 2)
label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

ID=StringVar()
box1 = Entry(root, bd = 4, textvariable = ID)
box1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

botonA = Button(root, text = "accept",command=lambda: get_data(mylist), width = 5)
botonA.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

list_names = Listbox(root).grid(row = 2, column = 1, rowspan = 7)
for item in mylist:
    list_names.insert("end", item)

root.mainloop()
```

---

With the help from Matteo, I was able to creat what I wanted. Thanks again for clearing this up for me! :)

```
{from tkinter import *

 root = Tk()
 root.title("Name Entry")
 root.geometry("240x250")

 mylist = []

 def get_data(l):
    l.append(box1.get())
    print(l)
    display_data()

def display_data():
    list_names.delete(0, "end")

    for items in mylist:
        list_names.insert(END, items)

label1 = Label(root,text = "ID:",height = 2)
label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

ID = StringVar()
box1 = Entry(root, bd = 4, textvariable = ID)
box1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

botonA = Button(root, text = "accept",command = lambda: get_data(mylist), 
width = 5)
botonA.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

list_names = Listbox(root)
list_names.grid(row = 2, column = 1, rowspan = 7)


root.mainloop()}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: How can an item be stored in an empty list? If there is something stored there, it won't be empty.

Answer (score 2):

You have to insert the element when the button is pressed! In your code you are adding it to the listbox when *mylist* was empty.

Here is the working code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Name Entry")
root.geometry("240x250")

mylist = []


def get_data(l):
    l.append(box1.get())
    list_names.insert(END, l)
    print(l)


label1 = Label(root, text="ID:", height=2)
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

ID = StringVar()
box1 = Entry(root, bd=4, textvariable=ID)
box1.grid(row=0, column=1)

botonA = Button(root, text="accept", command=lambda: get_data(mylist), width=5)
botonA.grid(row=0, column=2)

list_names = Listbox(root)
list_names.grid(row=2, column=1, rowspan=7)

root.mainloop()
```

I also modified two other things:

- I'm not sure if it's what you wanted but *l.append(box1.get())* adds to the listbox all the element of the list, and not just the last one as I think you need.
- *list_names = Listbox(root).grid(row = 2, column = 1, rowspan = 7)* means that the *list_names* variable is the result of the grid function (which is None). You have to first save the *ListBox* variable, and the grid it.

Comment: That is the problem - but does this work? Can the function see list_names?

Comment: Yeah, because *get_data* is runned after the listbox is created. Actually the code could be written in a better way, because it's never good to have a function that calls a global variable (in this case the listbox variable) which is not already created.

Comment: Guys! thanks for clearing that up for me!!!! Being new to python and knowing the difference between v2 and v3 is a bit tough. Matteo, using the data you provided I was able to create exactly what I was looking for. I also added a function to clear the names listed and then display in vertically.